# Calling GCP's API in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, httpclient

I'm looking over the [Google Cloud Client Libraries for .NET](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/index.html) and cannot find a way to create a TLS/SSL certificate on a load balancer.

In the console, I can fill out the form and click on the "Equivalent REST" to view the REST call:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/{my-project}/global/sslCertificates
{
  "description": "",
  "managed": {
    "domains": [
      "myexample.com"
    ]
  },
  "name": "testing-cert",
  "type": "MANAGED"
}
```

I'm assuming I'll use a standard HttpClient to make a POST the payload to that endpoint, however, how do I go about authenticating the client?

Comment: Google Cloud Client Libraries don't support the Compute API at the moment - for that you'd want the "old style" REST-based package of Google.Apis.Compute.v1. No need to use a standard HTTP client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your post I understand you have two separate questions.

The first one would be how to create an SSL certificate using the API for your Load Balancer, information on how this is done can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs#create-ssl) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/sslCertificates), where you will find additional information on SSLcertificates resources. To associate your certificate to the Load Balancer you can follow these guides, depending on your needs:

- [External HTTPS load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-https-lb-simple).
- [Setting up SSL Proxy Load Balancing](http://Setting%20up%20SSL%20Proxy%20Load%20Balancing)

For your second question about authenticating the client for API use, the following [guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#basicsteps) might prove useful to you.